# How to get list of file names from a private remote ip

Tags: ruby, linux, directory, net-ssh

I am having access to **ServerA** and don't have access to **ServerB**.I want to get the list of file names from **ServerB** via serverA.

I am logging into **ServerA** using the following command and doing some functions.

```
 Net::SSH.start(url, user, forward_agent: true) do |ssh|

  ssh.exec('scp -r source dest')
 end
```

But i want to get the list the file names from **ServerB** via **ServerA**. How can i do it ?

```
Eg: Dir["/path/*.txt"] or ls *.txt

OS: Linux
Language: ruby
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ssh to execute a remote command:

```
ssh username@hostname ls -l /foo/bar
```

If the `ls` command is not enough you can always use `find` or any other command.

**EDIT**

Here you have a full working script

```
require 'net/ssh'

Net::SSH.start('localhost', 'user', :password => "password") do |ssh|

  stdout = ''
  ssh.exec!("ls -l /tmp") do |channel, stream, data|
    stdout << data if stream == :stdout
  end
  puts stdout
end
```

working with ruby 2.1.2p95

Also make sure you have ruby compiled with OpenSSL:

```
ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'
```

**EDIT 2**

What you need is a tunnel, for more information check the [official documentation](https://github.com/jamis/net-ssh-gateway).

```
require 'net/ssh/gateway'

gateway = Net::SSH::Gateway.new('host', 'user')

gateway.ssh("host.private", "user") do |ssh|
  puts ssh.exec!("hostname")
end

gateway.open("host.private", 80) do |port|
  Net::HTTP.get_print("127.0.0.1", "/path", port)
end

gateway.shutdown!
```

Comment: If i execute the above command. Am getting empty result. i dont know why.Also i want to get only the file names.Am executing the command inside the Net::SSH.start loop.

Comment: @karan I've updated the answer with a working example.

Comment: I am login into ServerA using 
    Net::SSH.start(SERVERA, user,forward_agent: true) do |ssh|
 # need to run the command here for SERVERB
    end

I have don't direct access to SERVERB from my local system. i need to login to SERVERB via SERVERA.

Comment: @karan Another edit with a tunnel information, which should solve your issue.

Comment: Paulo Fidalgo - Using Gateway, its works. Thank you.